# Static Cells in UITableViewController error

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I set up a UITableViewController with static cells, but the compiler keeps on reporting:

> Static table views are only valid when embedded in
>   UITableViewController instances

Previously I had a viewController, but I built another controller in the StoryBoard and rebuilt it from scratch. I even tried associating the controller to a plain UITableViewController instead of my custom class, but the error sticks.
I also examined the source and the description seems correct:

```
<tableViewController storyboardIdentifier="taxiDetail" useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES" id="FDn-rG-NnT" customClass="taxiDetail" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

I tried changing the sceneMemberId, but if I set it to tableViewController, the storyboard turns corrupted.

What could it be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently a phantom tableView creeped in my storyboard source, notwithstanding nothing appeared in the graphic architecture. I deleted that part in the source and now it compiles fine.